# problem with tracert

Tags: networking

How does tracert work if the route to the destination gets disconnected or the link is damaged? what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive a response from the last router (AKA gateway) that has a route to the destination and then no further responses (typically * * *) to indicate no further responses from more distant routers.